# Is there a way to stop the function from returning the jsx till an asyn function is called in a React functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Please look at the following code:-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const Context = React.createContext();

export default function ImportBefore() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  (async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    setMessage("Antha Rama Mayam!");
  })();

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={message}>Message is {message}</Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

As I see the output initially it is "**Message is**" and later after the 5 seconds it is "**Message is Antha Rama Mayam**". This is as expected.

Is there a way to stop the return till the async function is returned and the message is set appropriately.

I tried with **Suspense** and **useState with Lazy Loading**. Also, **useEffect** did not add much value here. Is there a way out?

Answer (score 0):

No.

However, what you can do is return something like a loading spinner while `message` is empty or whatever else you could imagine. Perhaps just return an empty div?

```
return (
    {message ? (
        <Context.Provider value={message}>Message is {message}</Context.Provider>
    ) : (
        <div></div>
    )}
)
```